# My python function for find is returning None object though it is finding the key accurately

Tags: python, data-structures

I am writing a code to find Node with a particular key in a binary tree, though it is finding the Node correctly but returning None

```
def Find(key,root):
    if(root):
        if (key>root.key):
            print("going right")
            Find(key,root.right)
        elif (key<root.key):
            print("going left")
            Find(key,root.left)
        elif (key == root.key):
            print("found" )
            print(root)
            return root
        else :
            print("not in the tree")
            return 0

temp = Find(5, bt.root) //Find the node with key 5 in the tree
print(type(temp))

// Output >> 
<__main__.Node object at 0x000000F8A7DCAAC8>
<class 'NoneType>
```

Why it is returning None type as the function is clearly returning node

Comment: printing != returning

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `Find(key,root.right)` to `return Find(key,root.right)` (similarly for left).

Currently, when you are finding the element, you are not returning it, so the function implicitly returns `None`.

Comment: Yeah @blue_note it works fine now. Thanks